# C++ boost threadgroup.interrupt_all() causing main thread to exit too

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using the below code to create threads and add them to a thread pool. The threads load fine and each perform a simple looping routine until the main thread calls ResetWorkerThreads a second time and kills off the sub threads. The sub threads are interrupted however the main thread exits also. There are no errors written to console. I can't wrap my head around it as it doesn't appear to have any exception and the main thread has not been added to the vecThreads thread pool. Also the second time this function is all the "All Threads Killed" is not outputted as if it never reaches that point.

```
std::string strPreviousSettings = "0";
std::string strPreviousAgentSettings = "0";
bool boolResetWorkers;
std::string strIP;
std::string strMACAddress;
boost::thread_group vecThreads;

std::string GetIP()
{

    std::string strIP;

    try
    {
        using namespace boost::network;

        std::string strRequest;
        http::client client;

        http::client::request request("http://test.com/ip.php");
        http::client::response response = client.get(request);
        strIP = body(response);




    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "GetLocalIP - Error: " << endl;
    }

    return strIP;
}


std::string getMacAddress()
{
    std::string strMACAddress = GetFileContents("/sys/class/net/eth0/address");
    boost::replace_all(strMACAddress, ":", "");
    boost::replace_all(strMACAddress, "\n", "");
    return strMACAddress;
}


void ThreadSettingsWorker()
{
    int x = 1;
    strIP = GetIP();
    strMACAddress = getMacAddress();

    do {
        CheckEventSettings();
        CheckAgentSettings();

        if(boolResetWorkers==true)
        {
            ResetWorkerThreads();
        } else {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(3000));
        }


    } while ( x != 0 );
}

void ResetWorkerThreads()
{
    cout << "Resetting Workers Threads\n";
    boolResetWorkers = false;
    int intWorkerCount = 10; //Spawn 10 workers
    int X = 0;
    int intI = 1;

    cout << "Kill All Threads\n";

    try
    {
        vecThreads.interrupt_all();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Kill All Threads: " << std::endl;
    }

    cout << "All Threads Killed\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < intWorkerCount; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Starting Worker: " << (i + 1) << "\n";
        boost::thread tWorker(&ThreadWorker, (i + 1));
        vecThreads.add_thread(&tWorker);
    }




}


void TestRequest()
{
    try
    {
        using namespace boost::network;
        std::stringstream ss;
        http::client client;
        ss << "http://test.com/sadasdasd.html";
        http::client::request request(ss.str());
        http::client::response response = client.get(request);
        std::string strOutput = body(response);

        cout << "Test Request Out: " << strOutput << "\n";



    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "TestRequest - Error: " << endl;
        return;
    }
}



void ThreadWorker(int intThread)
{
    try
    {
        int X = 0;

        do {
            cout << "Thread " << intThread << "\n";
            TestRequest();
        } while ( X != 55 );
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}



void CheckEventSettings()
{

    try
    {
        using namespace boost::network;

        std::string strRequest;
        http::client client;
        http::client::request request("http://test.com/events.php");
        http::client::response response = client.get(request);
        std::string strOutput = body(response);


        if(strPreviousSettings==strOutput)
        {
            cout << "No Event Settings Changes\n";
        } else {

            cout << "Applying New Event Settings\n";
            strPreviousSettings = strOutput;
            std::string strDividerLine = "<br>";
            std::string strDividerField = "<field>";
            std::vector<std::string> vEvents;

            vEvents = EasySplit(strOutput, strDividerLine);

            for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iEvent = vEvents.begin(); iEvent != vEvents.end() - 1; ++iEvent) { 

            }


        }



    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "CheckEventSettings - Error: " << endl;
        return;
    }
}




void CheckAgentSettings()
{

    try
    {
        using namespace boost::network;
        std::stringstream ss;
        http::client client;
        ss << "http://test.com/checksettings.php";
        http::client::request request(ss.str());
        http::client::response response = client.get(request);
        std::string strOutput = body(response);

        if(strPreviousAgentSettings==strOutput)
        {
            cout << "No Agent Settings Changes\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Applying New Agent Settings\n";
            strPreviousAgentSettings = strOutput;
            boolResetWorkers = true;
        }



    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "CheckAgentSettings - Error: " << endl;
        return;
    }
}




int main()
{


    // Start thread
    boost::thread tCheckSettings(&ThreadSettingsWorker);


    // Ask thread to stop
    //tCheckSettings.interrupt();

    // Join - wait when thread actually exits
    tCheckSettings.join();



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you post a small version of main and a thread job which demonstrates the behavior?  There are several things that can be happening at the site you are calling this function from, or in the thread loop itself after the interrupt is called that can be giving you a problem.

Comment: Additional code has been posted, thanks.

Comment: There are still several layers that could be the issue.  I suggest that you start with the simplest example which uses a pool in one thread and the interrupt.  If that works, start slowing adding code back until it breaks.  That will narrow down what is failing and causing the behavior you are seeing.  I do see one issue though, and I'll add that to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
boost::thread tWorker(&ThreadWorker, (i + 1));
vecThreads.add_thread(&tWorker);
```

You create a local object `tWorker` that is deleted just after call to `add_thread()`. So vecThreads contains the dangling pointers to `thread`s. When you call `vecThreads.interrupt_all()` you get undefined behavior because `vecThreads` tries to access the deleted `thread` objects and I suppose your program just terminates because of access violation or something.

You have to change your code to something like this:

```
boost::thread* ptWorker = new boost::thread(&ThreadWorker, (i + 1));
vecThreads.add_thread(ptWorker);
```

Please note that you don't need to `delete` those `thread` objects yourself. `thread_group` will `delete` them itself.

**ADDITION:**
The problem with `terminate()` may be caused by destructor of `http::client` throwing an exception. Please try this to possibly eliminate that problem in `TestRequest()`:

```
try{
    http::client client;
    try{
        // other code
    }
    catch (){}
}
catch(){}
```

Also I'd suggest resetting `vecThreads` after `interrupt_all()`. For example you can define it as `boost::scoped_ptr` and then do `pvecThreads.reset(new boost::thread_group())` after the call to `interrupt_all()`.
At present the interrupted threads still remain in the `thread_group` after the interruption and then you try to `interrupt` them again along with the new threads added to the `thread_group` later in `ResetWorkerThreads()`.

Comment: I have made the adjustments in regard to the pointer but now I am facing a new error, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >'
  what():  boost thread: trying joining itself: Resource deadlock avoided

Comment: @user246181 Please try to move the declaration `http::client client;` from inside of `try` block. So the code should be `http::client client; try {...}` instead of `try{ http::client client; ...} `

Comment: @user246181 You should do it in all of your functions.

Comment: I have commented out the HTTP request code in TestRequest() function and now I get the below message and main thread still exits. boost::thread_interrupted'
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively

Comment: I'm starting to think the error now lies in the following code after it is executed a second time as cout calls before this code are executed and then the application terminates. for (int i = 0; i < intWorkerCount; ++i)
 {
  cout << "Starting Worker: " << (i + 1) << "\n";
  boost::thread* ptWorker = new boost::thread(&ThreadWorker, (i + 1));
  vecThreads.add_thread(ptWorker);
 }

Comment: I added boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)); inside the ThreadWorker loop and no longer get any errors, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user246181 I made an addition to my answer above in reply to your comments.

Comment: You were right, when I removed the try catch on the http the thread threw an exception and exited the loop, when it was left it the loop would continue as the exception was caught within the loop and not with the handling outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of ResetWorkerThreads You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intWorkerCount; ++i)
{
    cout << "Starting Worker: " << (i + 1) << "\n";
    // One issue is here, don't create a thread on the stack
    // and pass it to the thread group use new instead!
    boost::thread tWorker(&ThreadWorker, (i + 1));
    vecThreads.add_thread(&tWorker);
}
```

You are adding a thread created on the stack to the thread group.  As soon as you iterate over the loop that threads memory is invalidated.  You will need to `new` the thread and pass that pointer to add_thread.